# Error in Node.js - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backend

I was just trying to create a simple Express app and trying to save data using MongoDB. Everything went fine until I tried to add the status code. I've tried adding the status code using 3 different methods but nothing seems to work.

> Using Express 4.14.1

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');
var {Todo} = require('./models/todo');
var {User} = require('./models/user');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/todos', (req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    var todo = new Todo({
        text: req.body.text
    })

    todo.save().then( (doc) => {
        res.send("Doc saved : ", doc);
    }, (error) => {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    })

})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000")
});
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the todo is saved to the database? How are you sending requests to the server?

Comment: Is the save successful or not? Can you try logging doc and error and see what they print?

Answer (score 0):

Can you attach the error you are getting?

Have you tried this save method? I'm wondering if your save is not working.

```js
todo.save((err, todoresult) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error saving to user: ', err)
    return res.json(err)
  } else {
    res.json(todoresult);
  }
});
```

Comment: You almost always want to send a response to the client. Otherwise it will just hang. Commenting out the response if there is an error seems like a really bad idea in this case.